# A statistic for testing if $\mu$ which is known to be in subspace $H$, is also in subspace $H_0\subseteq H$

Tags: statistics

I have a problem called problem 2.19 from Mathematische statistiek by A. van der Vaart https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.j.k.kleijn/AsympStat-LecNotes2010.pdf

Before I state it, $P$ means the orthogonal projection onto $H$, $P_0$ same onto $H_0$ and $I-P$ same onto $H^{\bot}$. And $H_0$, $H$ are subspaces with $H_0\subseteq H\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Now the problem is:

"Suppose that $Y\sim N_n(\mu,{\sigma}^2I)$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are parameters that are known to belong a linear subspace $H$ and $(0,\infty)$, respectively. We wish to test $H_0: \mu\in H_0$ for a linear subspace $H_0\subseteq H$. As a test statistic we use $T=||P_0Y-PY||^2/||(I-P)Y||^2$. Show how an appropriate critical value can be obtained from a table of an $F$-distribution."

There is a theorem saying if $X\sim N(0,\Sigma)$ then $|X|^2\sim \sum_i \lambda_i Z_i^2$ with $\lambda_i$ all the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ and $Z_i\sim N(0,1)$. By looking at the proof it seems like it's also possible to make a version for general $\mu$.

I know that we can make a basis of $H_0$ and by extending it in a right way we can get a basis of $H$. I also have an ugly calculation to get the distribution of $|P_0Y-PY|^2$ and $|(I-P)Y|^2$.

But I don't see how this statistic works. Does anyone have a comment or answer? Thanks in advance (it's written that I'd better not thank in the comments).

Comment: I would highly recommend sending this over to CrossValidated instead of DataScience. In the meantime, you may be looking for something related to a likelihood ratio test (LRT). In an LRT, the test statistic has a chi-squared distribution, but the basic premise is to test if a nested model is adequate, or if a full model is needed. The premise here seems to be to test if mu is in a particular subspace, given it exists in a larger space. The idea is the same, but unfortunately I can't get beyond that.

Comment: Someone on math.stackexchange told me I can also post this problem here. Can you give a link to CrossValidated?

Comment: Already got the site CrossValidated. Thx for this info